# Show DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to show a dialog that gets input from the user (with an OK button) but I'm starting with with a yes or not which it isn't working. This code is crashing and I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated ;). If you could guide me to the prompt dialog would be even cooler ;p.

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            new TestDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");


        }
}
//=============================================
    public class TestDialog extends DialogFragment {
        Context mContext;
          public TestDialog() {
              mContext = getActivity();
                // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
            }

          @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Really?");
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                //null should be your on click listener
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                return alertDialogBuilder.create();
            }
```

Comment: Here is an example DialogFragment implementation from the official Android Documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

replaced mContext with getActivity(). I wasn't instantiating the object so mContext was null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create your `Dialog` until your `Fragment` has passed through its `onResume()` state.  I'm guessing you're getting an exception regarding an invalid state.